# Smaller set of rules in FxCOp 10.0?

Tags: upgrade, fxcop

I have used FxCop 1.36 and I recently upgarded to FxCop 10.0. Using the same set of rules and the same set of assemblies now I got less warnings.

Have they removed some rules from the FxCop 10.0? If so, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know of only one rule (Performance.DoNotInitializeUnnecessarily) that appears to have been completely removed in 10.0.  However, there are some other changes that may be affecting your violation counts:

1. The logic of several rules has been improved so that they will detect less false positives.  For example, there are some security rules that detect issues that are only problems when running on .NET 1.x.  If you target later framework versions, you should no longer see violations for these rules in FxCop 10.0.
2. The rules around security transparency have changed quite a bit.  Some old rules have been removed, but they've been replaced by other rules that should detect similar problems.  In addition, quite a few new transparency rules have been added.  Depending on whether you've upgraded your code to .NET 4.0 and how you've set up your transparency/criticality, you may be picking up less transparency violations than you did before.

Answer (score 0):

it's difficult to trac the different versions of fxcop. Is version 10 compatible with 3.6?
Can version 10 also profile .net 3.5 code?